# Make a horizontal ScrollView scroll itself when dragging a view inside of it via DragGesture() near it´s horizontal edges

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop, scrollview

This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761383/how-to-drag-a-view-inside-uiscrollview-with-scrolling-near-edges), however I would strongly prefer to implement this behaviour in SwiftUI natively. I have a horizontal `ScrollView`, which has multiple `HStack`s vertically inside of it, with my `CellView`s inside of them. The HStacks have a set width, which is quite big. The CellView has a `DragGesture()`, editing it´s `offset`. The `DragGesture` enables me to implement my custom Drag & Drop logic between the multiple HStacks.

I managed to get the `DragGesture`to work inside the ScrollView by adding `onTapGesture()` before it. However when I drag the Cell to the right or left edge of the screen, the `ScrollView` does not scroll automatically and I am forced to drop the dragged item and scroll myself. That opposes the whole point of Drag & Drop.

Is there a way for the ScrollView to start scrolling when dragging the Cell to one of the edges?

I tried to research this issue but to no success. As I understand it, ScrollView does not allow me to manually change the offset.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need a ScrollView at all, just implement an offset to a VStack instead. You are overriding all the native gestures.

Comment: @loremipsum Well I need to be able to scroll through the HStacks to view the content in them, which are the cells. It is a basically a long timeline view, like one you would have in a video editor. Do you suggest that I implement the scrolling functionality via setting the offset everytime a user swipes on the screen?